# Is there a way to integrate Craft with Magento?

Tags: plugins, login, ecommerce, integration

Is there a method or for integrating Craft with Magento?

We have a new project coming up and we've done this with EE, but would like to try with Craft.

Ideally it would be a single login, but if we can even just get it so that they share the same header/footer stuff, that would be awesome.  I know you can do this with WordPress too, but again, we'd rather use Craft here. And I know there is Craft Commerce, but it just doesn't have all of the functionality we need, where Magento does.

Has anyone integrated the two and/or have any suggestions?

Comment: We are integrating the two yes, not using a plugin but some curl stuff.